# ListView updates for one ArrayList but not for other [Widget]

Tags: java, android, listview, android-appwidget

I'm trying yo update my ListView in appwidget I can see list created If I use initData() but not for initDataFromService(). I'm populating mCollection with same type of data in both functions. I couldn't figure out what is the difference? Why its not updating?
Thanks.

I can provide any info needed.

Here is the WidgetDataProvider:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class WidgetDataProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String phonenumber;
    String personelno;

    ArrayList<Anlik> mCollections = new ArrayList<Anlik>();

    Context mContext = null;

    public WidgetDataProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCollections.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews mView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        mView.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, mCollections.get(position).toString());
        mView.setTextColor(android.R.id.text1, Color.BLACK);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        initData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        initData();
    }

    private void initData() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            mCollections.add(new Anlik("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","j"));
        }
    }

    private void initDataFromService() {

        sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", mContext.getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        phonenumber = sharedPreferences.getString("mPhonenumber", "");
        personelno = sharedPreferences.getString("mPersonalno", "");
        class AsyncAnlikCheck extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                anlikService(phonenumber, personelno);
                return null;
            }
        }
        AsyncAnlikCheck asyncanlikcheck = new AsyncAnlikCheck();
        asyncanlikcheck.execute();*/

    }

    public void anlikService(String phonenumber,String personalno){
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(LoginActivity.NAMESPACE,"MudoLife_getAnlikSatisAuth");

        request.addProperty("phoneNumber",phonenumber);
        request.addProperty("personelNumber",personalno);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(LoginActivity.URL);

        transportSE.debug=true;

        try{

            transportSE.call("http://tempuri.org/MudoLife_getAnlikSatisAuth",envelope);
            final SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            if(response.getPropertyCount()!=0){

                for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){
                    SoapObject anliklistt = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);
                    mCollections.add(new Anlik(anliklistt.getProperty("urnGrp").toString(),anliklistt.getProperty("ttr").toString(),anliklistt.getProperty("ttrGY").toString(),anliklistt.getProperty("degisim").toString(),anliklistt.getProperty("resim").toString(),anliklistt.getProperty("marj").toString(),anliklistt.getProperty("marjGY").toString(),anliklistt.getProperty("marjDegisim").toString(),anliklistt.getProperty("marjResim").toString()));
                }
                //Collections.sort(mCollections, Anlik.COMPARE_BY_BIRIM);

            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure that you pass the correct values in your anlinkService() ? is phonenumber and personalno correct?

Comment: yeah. I checked the final list after initDataFromService() even that is correct.

Comment: you mean your mCollections list?

Comment: yep. I just added some logs to check what is the problem. I added ` Log.d("DEBUG", "funcName(): returned " + mCollections.toString()); ` to end of functions to see where data is lost. this is the result

Comment: `04-11 08:51:49.429 9199-9199/com.mudolife.kubilayaydin.mudolifeapp D/DEBUG: onCreate: returned []
04-11 08:51:49.439 9199-9211/com.mudolife.kubilayaydin.mudolifeapp D/DEBUG: onDataFromService: returned []
04-11 08:51:49.439 9199-9211/com.mudolife.kubilayaydin.mudolifeapp D/DEBUG: onDataSetChanged: returned []
04-11 08:51:49.449 9199-9800/com.mudolife.kubilayaydin.mudolifeapp D/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: onDataFromService: returned []

04-11 08:51:51.649 9199-9801/com.mudolife.kubilayaydin.mudolifeapp D/DEBUG: doInBackground: returned Here is the correct list (too long couldnt add)`

Comment: mCollections updates after onCreate or onDataSetChanged functions I guess?

Comment: ok, but are you sure the list is not filled from initData() method? Because you are calling this in onCreate() and in onDataSetChanged(). Are you sure you are not calling initData() before starting initDataFromService()? sorry for my questions but I can´t see any issues here and have to check step by step.

Comment: I changed both onCreate() and onDataSetChanget(). They are both calling initDataFromService() but there is no change

Comment: I think you have to update your remotviews in onPostExecute. I am assuming that the list is generated but at the end when the list is updated, the remoteviews aren´t. If you call onCreate() it will be called by adding the widget to the homescreen. But Asynctask doing its work beyond all other things will be done...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs solved it by Void res = asyncanlikcheck.execute().get(); It says if I use get it waits for computation to complete. Now I can see my results. Thanks for trying to help :)